# Mediapipe - Differentiated extraction of hand landmarks based on handedness (right and left) in a C++ framework

Tags: c++, object-detection, mediapipe, video-tracking

I am writing a calculator in C++ "Hand_Landmark_Write_To_File_Calculator" to write in a file the normalized position of the hand mark (x, y, z) as a function of the handedness.

The inputs to my calculator are :

- input_stream: "HANDEDNESS:handedness"
  Handedness of the detected hand (i.e. is the hand left or right). (`std::vector<ClassificationList>`)
- input_stream: "LANDMARKS:landmarks"
  Collection of detected/predicted hands, each represented as a list of landmarks. (`std::vector<NormalizedLandmarkList>`)

My calculator has been added to the "`hand_trancking_desktop_live.pbtxt`" graph provided in the Mediapipe example, so that both inputs come from the output of the "`HandLandmarkTrackingCpu`" node.

**Graph**

```
# CPU image. (ImageFrame)
input_stream: "input_video"

# CPU image. (ImageFrame)
output_stream: "output_video"

# Generates side packet cotaining max number of hands to detect/track.
node {
  calculator: "ConstantSidePacketCalculator"
  output_side_packet: "PACKET:num_hands"
  node_options: {
    [type.googleapis.com/mediapipe.ConstantSidePacketCalculatorOptions]: {
      packet { int_value: 2 }
    }
  }
}

# Detects/tracks hand landmarks.
node {
  calculator: "HandLandmarkTrackingCpu"
  input_stream: "IMAGE:input_video"
  input_side_packet: "NUM_HANDS:num_hands"
  output_stream: "LANDMARKS:landmarks"
  output_stream: "HANDEDNESS:handedness"
  output_stream: "PALM_DETECTIONS:multi_palm_detections"
  output_stream: "HAND_ROIS_FROM_LANDMARKS:multi_hand_rects"
  output_stream: "HAND_ROIS_FROM_PALM_DETECTIONS:multi_palm_rects"
}

node {
  calculator: "HandLandmarkWriteToFileCalculator"
  input_stream: "LANDMARKS:landmarks"
  input_stream: "HANDEDNESS:handedness"
}

# Subgraph that renders annotations and overlays them on top of the input
# images (see hand_renderer_cpu.pbtxt).
node {
  calculator: "HandRendererSubgraph"
  input_stream: "IMAGE:input_video"
  input_stream: "DETECTIONS:multi_palm_detections"
  input_stream: "LANDMARKS:landmarks"
  input_stream: "HANDEDNESS:handedness"
  input_stream: "NORM_RECTS:0:multi_palm_rects"
  input_stream: "NORM_RECTS:1:multi_hand_rects"
  output_stream: "IMAGE:output_video"
}
```

At the moment I am only trying to display the position of the hands in the standard output according to the Handedness label.

**Calculators code :**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "mediapipe/framework/calculator_framework.h"
#include "mediapipe/framework/port/canonical_errors.h"
#include "mediapipe/tasks/cc/components/containers/landmark.h"
#include "mediapipe/framework/formats/classification.pb.h"

namespace mediapipe {

class HandLandmarkWriteToFileCalculator : public CalculatorBase {
 public:
  static absl::Status GetContract(CalculatorContract* cc) {
    cc->Inputs().Tag("LANDMARKS").Set<std::vector<NormalizedLandmarkList>>();
    cc->Inputs().Tag("HANDEDNESS").Set<std::vector<ClassificationList>>();
    return absl::OkStatus();
    }

  absl::Status Open(CalculatorContext* cc) final { return absl::OkStatus(); }
  absl::Status Process(CalculatorContext* cc) final {
    const auto& input_landmarks =
    cc->Inputs().Tag("LANDMARKS").Get<std::vector<NormalizedLandmarkList>>();
            
    const std::vector<ClassificationList>& classifications =
    cc->Inputs().Tag("HANDEDNESS").Get<std::vector<ClassificationList>>();
        
    std::string label;
    for (int i = 0; i < classifications.size(); i++)
    {
        label = classifications[i].classification(0).label();
        if (label.compare("Right") == 1) {
            std::cout << "Right : " << input_landmarks[0].landmark(0).x() << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Left : " << input_landmarks[0].landmark(0).x() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return absl::OkStatus();
    }
};
REGISTER_CALCULATOR(HandLandmarkWriteToFileCalculator);

}  // namespace mediapipe
```

If only one hand appears on the webcam, then this code correctly displays the x-coordinate with the correct hand label.
However, if both hands appear on the webcam, the index 0 of the `input_landmarks` vector corresponds to the first hand that could be detected. So if my right hand is detected before my left hand the standard output will show for "Right: " & "Left: " the same x coordinate corresponding to my right hand. Conversely, if my left hand is detected first, the index 0 will now correspond to my left hand and the standard output will only display the x-coordinate of my left hand.

**How can I match the Handedness to the coordinates of the corresponding hand, when two hands are detected ?**

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.

The issue was with the graph `hand_tracking_desktop_live.pbtxt`, where the output stream `LANDMARKS:landmarks` is of type `std::vector<NormalizedLandmarkList>`. This vector contains the landmarks of each hand, but the handedness associated with each index changes depending on the first hand detected.

To solve this problem, i moved the `Hand_Landmark_Write_To_File_Calculator` node into the `HandLandMarkTrackingCpu` calculator graph.

In this graph, each hand is first processed separately, and then the handedness and landmarks of each hand are collected and grouped within the vector.

So, I added the `Hand_Landmark_Write_To_File_Calculator` node after the detection of the landmarks and the handedness of each isolated hand and before the collection of this data into vectors. As follows :

**Graph hand_landmark_tracking_cpu.pbtxt:**

```
# Detect hand landmarks for the specific hand rect.
node {
  calculator: "HandLandmarkCpu"
  input_side_packet: "MODEL_COMPLEXITY:model_complexity"
  input_stream: "IMAGE:image_for_landmarks"
  input_stream: "ROI:single_hand_rect"
  output_stream: "LANDMARKS:single_hand_landmarks"
  output_stream: "WORLD_LANDMARKS:single_hand_world_landmarks"
  output_stream: "HANDEDNESS:single_handedness"
}

# [MY ADDED CALCULATOR] Write Handlandmarks to file.
node {
  calculator: "HandLandmarkWriteToFileCalculator"
  input_stream: "LANDMARKS:single_hand_landmarks"
  input_stream: "HANDEDNESS:single_handedness"
}

# Collects the handedness for each single hand into a vector. Upon receiving the
# BATCH_END timestamp, outputs a vector of ClassificationList at the BATCH_END
# timestamp.
node {
  calculator: "EndLoopClassificationListCalculator"
  input_stream: "ITEM:single_handedness"
  input_stream: "BATCH_END:hand_rects_timestamp"
  output_stream: "ITERABLE:multi_handedness"
}

# Calculate region of interest (ROI) based on detected hand landmarks to reuse
# on the subsequent runs of the graph.
node {
  calculator: "HandLandmarkLandmarksToRoi"
  input_stream: "IMAGE_SIZE:image_size_for_landmarks"
  input_stream: "LANDMARKS:single_hand_landmarks"
  output_stream: "ROI:single_hand_rect_from_landmarks"
}
```

I have adapted my C++ code like this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "mediapipe/framework/calculator_framework.h"
#include "mediapipe/framework/port/canonical_errors.h"
#include "mediapipe/tasks/cc/components/containers/landmark.h"
#include "mediapipe/framework/formats/classification.pb.h"

namespace mediapipe {

class HandLandmarkWriteToFileCalculator : public CalculatorBase {
 public:
  static absl::Status GetContract(CalculatorContract* cc) {
    cc->Inputs().Tag("LANDMARKS").Set<NormalizedLandmarkList>();
    cc->Inputs().Tag("HANDEDNESS").Set<ClassificationList>();
    return absl::OkStatus();
    }

  absl::Status Open(CalculatorContext* cc) final { return absl::OkStatus(); }

  absl::Status Process(CalculatorContext* cc) final {
    const auto& input_landmarks =
    cc->Inputs().Tag("LANDMARKS").Get<NormalizedLandmarkList>();
            
    const ClassificationList& input_handedness =
    cc->Inputs().Tag("HANDEDNESS").Get<ClassificationList>();
        
    std::string label;
    label = input_handedness.classification(0).label();
    if (label.compare("Right") == 1) {
        std::cout << "Right: " << input_landmarks.landmark(0).x() << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Left : " << input_landmarks.landmark(0).x() << std::endl;
    }
    return absl::OkStatus();
    }
};
REGISTER_CALCULATOR(HandLandmarkWriteToFileCalculator);

}  // namespace mediapipe
```

**I hope this answer will help others.**